# apt-get + dpkg error after compiling and installing minidlna from source

Tags: apt, dpkg, minidlna

I am running 14.04.1. I followed [this guide](http://www.htpcbeginner.com/install-minidlna-on-ubuntu-ultimate-guide/) to compile and install miniDLNA from source a while back. Ever since then, when I run  `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y`, I get the following error after it completes:

```
dpkg: error processing package minidlna (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I get `apt-get` and `dpkg` to play nice with my custom install? I have compiled `.deb` packages and installed them without this error before, why might this one be giving me trouble?

Here is the command line input/output:

```
htpc@htpc-w500:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libblas3 libgfortran3 liblapack3 libmikmod2 libportmidi0 libsdl-mixer1.2
  libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libsmpeg0 linux-headers-3.19.0-25
  linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic python-appindicator python-numpy
  python-pygame
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  liboxideqt-qmlplugin liboxideqtcore0 liboxideqtquick0
  linux-generic-lts-vivid linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid
  linux-image-generic-lts-vivid oxideqt-codecs-extra
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up minidlna (1.1.2+dfsg-1~ubuntu14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package minidlna (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 minidlna
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here are the relevant lines from `/var/log/dpkg.log`:

```
2016-03-07 02:05:58 startup packages configure
2016-03-07 02:05:58 configure minidlna:amd64 1.1.2+dfsg-1~ubuntu14.04.1 <none>
2016-03-07 02:05:58 status half-configured minidlna:amd64 1.1.2+dfsg-1~ubuntu14.04.1
```

Comment: The error message you posted is incomplete. Please [edit] your question with the full error you get on running dpkg.

Comment: I added the I/O from running `apt-get`. I am not running dpkg directly. Is there a log that I should look at that might provide more helpful information?

Comment: What does `sudo dpkg --configure -a` do? Same error?

Comment: Strangely enough, I don't get an error when running `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. Still getting the same error with `apt-get` though.